# Magento Newsletter large collection handle

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, grid, newsletter

In my magento application 4lakhs customer have newsletter subscription,when i like to see the subscription grid in magento admin,it show the blank page.

**The existing query is**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('newsletter/subscriber_collection')
```

I also see the large collection handler in Magento, but i don't know how to write the large collection with this subscriber_collection.

Can you share your idea about how to handle the large newsletter collection in magento. thanks in advance for your answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically blank page is only shown when there is any error occurred. Can you please verify Magento exception log or server error log file which might be logged any entry for blank page error.

Subscriber Grid

### [image]

Newsletter Subscriber Grid Collection SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `main_table`.*, 
    `customer_lastname_table`.`value` AS `customer_lastname`, 
    `customer_firstname_table`.`value` AS `customer_firstname`, 
    IF(main_table.customer_id = 0, 1, 2) AS `type`, 
    `store`.`group_id`, 
    `store`.`website_id` 

FROM `newsletter_subscriber` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `customer_lastname_table` ON customer_lastname_table.entity_id=main_table.customer_id
                 AND customer_lastname_table.attribute_id = 7
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `customer_firstname_table` ON customer_firstname_table.entity_id=main_table.customer_id
                 AND customer_firstname_table.attribute_id = 5
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `store` ON store.store_id = main_table.store_id
```

---

In **_prepareCollection()** of **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid** [*app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php*] class Magento will instantiate newsletter collection as below. You can also instantiate same thing in you code.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('newsletter/subscriber_collection');
/* @var $collection Mage_Newsletter_Model_Mysql4_Subscriber_Collection */
$collection
    ->showCustomerInfo(true)
    ->addSubscriberTypeField()
    ->showStoreInfo();
```

Comment: if suppose in my application having 1000 records means, its working fine.so the problem in large customer collection.

Comment: @senthil Please go through exception logs, it will gives you exact reason behind that.

Comment: the problem is the usertype, firstname, lastname not show, when i have nearly 4 laksh record, i attached screen in my question for your better understanding

Comment: Its seems grid is working now instead of blank page, apart from that can you please randomly check database entries for empty User Type, Subscriber First Name, Subscriber Last Name. It helps you to figure out the issue.

Comment: yes you are right, i also check the customer grid regarding the firstname,lastname and usertype. but it having the value, this is not only show on the newsletter subscription grid. i attached the 3rd screen for your referrence. is there have any way to find the problem

Comment: How you used any extension for newsletter subscriber? Which Magento version your site is running?

Comment: No i only used the magento default newsletter. only i change the usertype(clinet/lawyer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34061/discussion-between-jayesh-patel-and-senthil).

Comment: I guess there might be any third party extension involved in newsletter subscription. You can see the grid title is different in your's as compare to mine.

Comment: Yes, in my application no store concept so i just hide the column only with extend the newsletter moduel.

Comment: At last run query added in answer which will be set to Newsletter Subscriber Grid. Hope will help for further troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks for your query,is this working fine in phpmyadmin, how to write this query in my magento query builder ?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine in phpmyadmin. You get more detail about this collection in **_prepareCollection()** method of **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid** class. Try to instantiate collection same as mentioned in this method.

Comment: can you past the query here, i can not able to predict where it was.

Comment: Answer updated please go through for further updates I attached query for for newsletter subscriber list & code snippet for use newsletter subscriber collection.